# Vaadin grid dynamic data display

Tags: vaadin-grid

i am trying to use vaadin grid element. Need to populate it with dynamic data. i.e. column names and count can change.

Trying to use as shown below. Using template, trying to repeat over the col element and the header elements. So as to create the grid dynamically.

It gives error message:

> Uncaught Class$S69
>
> (anonymous function) @ vaadin-grid.min.js:57

Is it possible to load dynamic data (where column names and count can change dynamically) in vaadin grid. if yes, then please guide how to achieve it ?
Let me know if you need more info from me.

```
<vaadin-grid id='grid' selection-mode="multi" size="1000">
                  <table>
                    <colgroup>
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columnNames}}" as="columnName">
                            <col name='{{columnName}}'>
                        </template>
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columnNames}}" as="columnName">
                              <th>{{columnName}}</th>
                          </template>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>
                </vaadin-grid>


_featureTableDataChanged: function(data){
                if(this.isReady){
                    this.convertToJSObj(data);
                    this.$.grid.items = this.jsDataObjArr;
                }
            },
            
            convertToJSObj: function(data){
                this.columnNames = data[0];
                var actualData = data.splice(1, data.length);
                
                for(var rowIndex in actualData){
                    var columnIndex = 0;
                    var rowObj = {};
                    
                    for(var columnName in this.columnNames){
                        rowObj[this.columnNames[columnName]] = actualData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                        columnIndex++;
                    }
                    
                    this.jsDataObjArr.push(rowObj);
                }
            }
```